# Use Gram-Schmidt to find an orthonormal basis of a product of two polynomials.

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products, orthonormal, gram-schmidt

Given $n = 4, x_1 = 1, x_2 = 0, x_3 = 2, x_4 = 3, and B = span\{1, t, t^2\}$, find an orthonormal basis of B under the scalar product

$\sum_{i=1} ^{n} p(x_i)q(x_i)$

using Gram Schmidt.

I am very new to this and a bit confused.

Comment: Gram-Schmidt is not difficult if you take it step by step. The bit that students are most likely to trip up on, in my experience, is remembering that $\|p(x)\|$ means $\sqrt{\langle p(x), p(x)\rangle}$. What is the first step for applying the procedure (there are a couple of variants of Gram-Schmidt)? How did you go when you tried to follow it? That is, where did you get stuck?

Comment: Can you do Gram-Schmidt in the basic case, say for vectors $p,q,r$ in $\mathbb R^3$?  If so, this problem is EXACTLY the same, only instead of computing $p\cdot q$ etc in the usual way, you do it by means of the formula you have stated.

Comment: @TheoBendit I am stuck specifically at how to incorporate the different x values into the Gram Schmidt process.

Comment: @No_Bass Oh right! So the problem is computing the inner product? Maybe it would help to expand the sum:\begin{align}\langle p,q\rangle&=p(x_1)q(x_1)+p(x_2)q(x_2)+p(x_3)q(x_3)+p(x_4)q(x_4)\\&=p(1)q(1)+p(0)q(0)+p(3)q(3)+p(4)q(4).\end{align}For example, if we take $p(t) = 1$ and $q(t) = t$, then we would compute the inner product like so:\begin{align}\langle p,q\rangle&=p(1)q(1)+p(0)q(0)+p(3)q(3)+p(4)q(4)\\&=1\cdot1+1\cdot0+1\cdot3+1\cdot4=8.\end{align}Does that help?

Comment: @peterwhy Good point. I think I started reading subscripts instead. It should be,\begin{align}\langle p,q\rangle&=p(1)q(1)+p(0)q(0)+p(2)q(2)+p(3)q(3)\\&=1\cdot1+1\cdot0+1\cdot2+1\cdot3=6.\end{align}